# Webpack 4 --> configuration[0] has an unknown property 'optimization'

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack @4.8.1 and when I run it. I get this error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration[0] has an unknown property 'optimization'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
```

I am guessing this has to do something with webpack 4. I think that I am either forgetting something here or I have not installed a dependency package that I may need. Not totally sure though.
Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Which version of serverless-webpack are you using? I run into the same, upgraded to serverless-webpack@latest (5.x) and it's working again.

Comment: Seemed to fix it for me thank you!

Comment: @DavidC & Taylor Austin — Can this be added as an accepted answer?